# chaining using getElementsByClassName and getElementById in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Following javascript code throws error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'getElementById'
```

If this is not allowed how do I search for the existence of particular element inside other element?

```
var googlePlusPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("mo fj");

for (var i = 0; i <  googlePlusPosts .length; ++i) {
        decryptElements = googlePlusPosts[i].getElementById('decrypt-button');
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why are you calling getElementById inside a loop? There should be only one element with that id in the entire document

Comment: `.getElementById()` is a method of the `document` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique; thus it doesn't really make sense to look inside a particular node for a particular ID; either the ID exists, or it doesn't.

You can use element.getElementsByClassName to get child elements of a particular class, or element.getElementsByTagName to get them by their tag name.

EDIT: Ignore the below; just saved for posterity.

Check if the element has the getElementById method ahead of time.

```
if (foo.getElementById) {
  foo.getElementById("bar");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question: the asker wants to do something like jQuery's `$("#id .class")` with normal dom methods.

Comment: if element is not having that method then how do i check if its descendants contain particular node ?

Answer (score 3):

getElementById is not part of the Element interface, it's part of the Document interface. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId

so getting elements by ID can only be done by calling `document.getElementById`. This is totally correct in the spec as there can only be **one** element with a specified ID in a document, so I actually sense that the problem is in your code to start with (looks like you have more than one element with the id "decrypt-button").

As for the chaining, if you can ensure you are in a browser that has the querySelector interface, you can do `googlePlusPosts[i].querySelector('#decrypt-button');` which is still wrong as you should use a class instead of an id and have `.decrypt-button`

Answer (score 0):

In [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector#compat-desktop), you can use `querySelector`:

```
googlePlusPosts[i].querySelector("#decrypt-button")
```

Otherwise, you're best using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to cover older browsers that don't implement `.querySelector()`, and you're not using some framework/library that already has a built-in method, a way to check if a particular element contains another element is to write your own function that uses [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode), something like this:

```
function isDescendant(p, c) {
   while (null != (c = c.parentNode))
      if (p === c)
         return true;

   return false;
}

// then, from your code:

var decryptButton =document.getElementById("decrypt-button");
for (var i = 0; i <  googlePlusPosts .length; ++i)
   if (isDescendant(googlePlusPosts[i], decryptButton))
      // do something
```